# flurry in IOS application

Tags: iphone

I am using flurry in my IOS application, i have many question in this :

1. is the file libFlurry necessary to add ( i am just using Flurry analytics)
2. i have done this in myAppDelegate.m

   ```
   [FlurryAPI startSession:@"VmyKey"];

   [FlurryAPI logAllPageViews:self.navController];
   ```

What i will see with the instruction :

```
    [FlurryAPI logAllPageViews:self.navController];
```

1. i would like to disable sending data when my app is down, i have done this in my app delegate : `[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:NO];` is this write ?
2. I wlould like to create events in my app, i have done like this : `[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"];` , where i will put this please ? i put it in the each viewController ( viewDidload) ??
3. What is the difference between :

   ```
   [FlurryAPI logAllPageViews:self.navController];

   [FlurryAPI logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"]
   ```

thanks for your answer

Answer (score 7):

```
[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"];
```

Use logEvent to count the number of times certain events happen during a session of your application. This can be useful for measuring how often users perform various actions

```
[FlurryAPI logAllPageViews:navigationController];
```

To enable Flurry agent to automatically detect and log page view, pass in an instance of UINavigationController or UITabBarController to logAllPageViews. Flurry agent will create a delegate on your object to detect user interactions. Each detected user interaction will automatically be logged as a page view. Each instance needs to only be passed to Flurry agent once. Multiple UINavigationController or UITabBarController instances can be passed to Flurry agent

```
[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:(BOOL)sendSessionReportsOnClose];
```

This option is on by default. When enabled, Flurry will attempt to send session data when the app is exited as well as it normally does when the app is started. This will improve the speed at which your application analytics are updated but can prolong the app termination process due to network latency. In some cases, the network latency can cause the app to crash.

Comment: Great answer. May I ask how you obtained that info?

Comment: If you look at the new application page in Flurry's dashboard, there is extensive documentation. This looks like an excerpt from that. Also checkout the header file included with the library.

Comment: What is EVENT_NAME here?